# Geting the type from using keyword in derived classes

Tags: c++

Consider

```
struct AbstractClass {};

struct Derived1 : AbstractClass {
    using type = int;
};

struct Derived2 : AbstractClass {
    using type = char;
};

struct Derived3 : AbstractClass {
    using type = bool;
};

int main() {
    AbstractClass* a[] = {new Derived1, new Derived2, new Derived3};
}
```

How to get `type` from a[0], a[1], a[2]?

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish.  I guess there is no other way to do this than this?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Object { virtual ~Object() = default; };
struct A : Object {};
struct B : Object {};
struct C : Object {};

struct AbstractClass {
    virtual void take (Object*) {
        std::cout << "Accepted.\n";
    }
};

template <typename...> struct ObjectTypes;

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct ObjectTypes<First, Rest...> : ObjectTypes<Rest...> {
    bool operator()(Object* o) const {
        if (dynamic_cast<First*>(o))
            return true;
        return ObjectTypes<Rest...>::operator()(o);
    }
};

template <>
struct ObjectTypes<> {
    bool operator()(Object*) const {return false;}
};

struct Derived1 : AbstractClass {
    using type = ObjectTypes<A,B>;
    virtual void take (Object* o) override {
        if (type()(o))  // This is why I want to use type from AbstractClass.
            return AbstractClass::take(o);
        std::cout << "Rejected.\n";
    }   
};

struct Derived2 : AbstractClass {
    using type = ObjectTypes<A,C>;
    virtual void take (Object* o) override {
        if (type()(o))
            return AbstractClass::take(o);
        std::cout << "Rejected.\n";
    }   
};

struct Derived3 : AbstractClass {
    using type = ObjectTypes<B,C>;
    virtual void take (Object* o) override {
        if (type()(o))
            return AbstractClass::take(o);
        std::cout << "Rejected.\n";
    }   
};

int main() {
    AbstractClass* abs[] = {new Derived1, new Derived2, new Derived3};
    A* a = new A;
    B* b = new B;
    C* c = new C;
    for (AbstractClass* x : abs) {
        x->take(a);
        x->take(b);
        x->take(c);
        std::cout << "------------\n";
    }
}
```

Notice the repetitions in Derived1, Derived2, Derived3, etc...?  Hence my original goal was to have it all done in the base class AbstractClass.

Comment: You can't. Types must be known at compile time. If you explain what you're actually trying to do, we might be able to help you find a solution.

Comment: @Brian.  Suppose I have `AbstractClass* a`.  Since `AbstractClass` is abstract, `*a` has `type` defined, and I need to use it.

Comment: No, I mean more broadly, what is this going to be used for?

Comment: @prestokeys: `*a` *does not* have `type` defined, because that's only in the derived classes. You're not going to get this to work as proposed because types are only available at compile-time, and accessing derived classes through a base class pointer is a strictly run-time thing, when types no longer exist. You'll need to explain why you need this, so we can suggest something you can actually *do.*

Comment: The full explanation has a lot of background.  I have a semi-explanation with an update to my question.

Comment: I think the functionality which uses your type need to be include in the DerivedClasses. Throwing it away from the class is just incorrect from the object oriented paradigm...

Comment: In other words if you want to do something with the type what is stopping you from doing it inside virtual method..?

Comment: You can't take a `type_info` or `type_index` and convert it back into a type, if that's what you were thinking. C++ doesn't have reflection. It's a statically typed language that destroys type information when it's compiled.

Comment: I've revised my question. And illustrated my goal using virtual methods.  The repetitions in the derived classes should show my motivation for obtaining `type` in the base class.

Comment: Maybe you could create the `virtual operator() (Object *) = 0;` inside the base `ObjectTypes`. Inside `AbstractClass` create a field of type `ObjectTypes *` then throw the take mathod into the `AbstractClass` and in the `DerivedClass`es constructor initialize the field of type `ObjectTypes *` with appropriate type?

Comment: @Wojciech Frohmberg.  Could you possibly write a solution?  It shouldn't be long, but I don't understand how ObjectTypes* can be a data member of AbstractClass when it has templates, or perhaps I totally misunderstand you.  `virtual operator() (Object *)` is pure virtual in which template base class `ObjectTypes`?  `ObjectTypes<T>` for any T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather thought about sth like:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Object { virtual ~Object() = default; };
struct A : Object {};
struct B : Object {};
struct C : Object {};

struct SuperObjectType {
public:
    virtual bool operator()(Object *o) const = 0;
};

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct ObjectTypes: SuperObjectType {
    bool operator()(Object* o) const override {
        if (dynamic_cast<First*>(o))
            return true;
        return ObjectTypes<Rest...>()(o);
    }
};

template <typename OnlyOne>
struct ObjectTypes<OnlyOne>: SuperObjectType {
    bool operator()(Object* o) const override {
        return dynamic_cast<OnlyOne*>(o);
    }
};

struct AbstractClass {
    SuperObjectType *sot;
    void take (Object* o) {
        if ((*sot)(o)) {
            std::cout << "ACCEPTED" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "REJECTED" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
struct Derived1 : AbstractClass {
    Derived1()  {
        sot = new ObjectTypes<A,B>;
    }
};

struct Derived2 : AbstractClass {
    Derived2() {
        sot = new ObjectTypes<A,C>;
    }
};

struct Derived3 : AbstractClass {
    Derived3() {
        sot = new ObjectTypes<B,C>;
    }
};

int main() {
    AbstractClass* abs[] = {new Derived1, new Derived2, new Derived3};
    A* a = new A;
    B* b = new B;
    C* c = new C;
    for (AbstractClass* x : abs) {
        x->take(a);
        x->take(b);
        x->take(c);
        std::cout << "------------\n";
    }
}
```

But I'm happy I've inspired you ;)

Minor alternative to (perhaps) speed up the performance:

```
template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct ObjectTypes: ObjectTypes<Rest...> {  // Derive from ObjectTypes<Rest...> instead.
    virtual bool operator()(Object* o) const override {
        if (dynamic_cast<First*>(o))
            return true;
        return ObjectTypes<Rest...>::operator()(o);
        // So now ObjectTypes<Rest...>::operator() can be used, and thus avoid instantiation.
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct ObjectTypes<T>: SuperObjectType {
    virtual bool operator()(Object* o) const override {
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(o);
    }
};
```

Because `ObjectTypes<T>` is derived from SuperObjectType for any type T, then `ObjectTypes<First, Rest...>` is derived from SuperObjectType as well (by being derived from `ObjectTypes<Last>`, were Last is the last type in Rest...).  So everything still works (tested).

Comment: That's a beautiful solution.  I never thought of homogeonizing `ObjectTypes<Ts...>' with a parent to create a field for AbstractClass.  It would be interesting to benchmark both solution to see which one performs faster.  Though I think both will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation. This is actually the first thing that came to my mind to solve your problem. I think though your solution is equally good.

Comment: I benchmarked that yours performs faster due to no v-table lookup and no dynamic casting (at a small cost of 4 bytes of memory footprint). Edit: Both solutions have the same byte size for AbstractClass because mine has a virtual function, so yours wins.

Comment: Nice! Who knew...? :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution inspired by Wojciech Frohmberg's suggestion, though I'm not sure this is what he meant.  I actually don't know what he meant and I think he meant something else, and would like to see his solution and find out what he was actually saying.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Object { virtual ~Object() = default; };
struct A : Object {};
struct B : Object {};
struct C : Object {};

template <typename...> struct ObjectTypes;

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct ObjectTypes<First, Rest...> : ObjectTypes<Rest...> {
    bool operator()(Object* o) const {
        if (dynamic_cast<First*>(o))
            return true;
        return ObjectTypes<Rest...>::operator()(o);
    }
};

template <>
struct ObjectTypes<> {
    bool operator()(Object*) const {return false;}
};

struct AbstractClass {
    virtual void take (Object*) = 0;
    template <typename... Ts> void takeHelper (Object* o, ObjectTypes<Ts...>&& types) {
        if (types(o)) std::cout << "Accepted.\n";  // And now do whatever with o.
        else std::cout << "Rejected.\n";
    }
};

template <typename Derived>
struct AbstractClassCRTP : AbstractClass {
    virtual void take (Object* o) override {
        takeHelper(o, typename Derived::type{});
    }
};

struct Derived1 : AbstractClassCRTP<Derived1> {
    using type = ObjectTypes<A,B>;
};

struct Derived2 : AbstractClassCRTP<Derived2> {
    using type = ObjectTypes<A,C>;
};

struct Derived3 : AbstractClassCRTP<Derived3> {
    using type = ObjectTypes<B,C>;
};

int main() {
    AbstractClass* abs[] = {new Derived1, new Derived2, new Derived3};
    A* a = new A;
    B* b = new B;
    C* c = new C;
    for (AbstractClass* x : abs) {
        x->take(a);
        x->take(b);
        x->take(c);
        std::cout << "------------\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Accepted.
Accepted.
Rejected.
------------
Accepted.
Rejected.
Accepted.
------------
Rejected.
Accepted.
Accepted.
```